# Google File System Read consistency

Tags: file, system, gfs

Does google file system provide read consistency. I am confused because I know that the primary maintains write consistency in GFS. If a system provided write consistency is it not that it provides read consistency also?

Thanks
Manjit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The read operation won't mutate the data, there is no concern about the consistency.